# Use first paragraph instead of first line in Sphinx autosummary

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using the [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) autosummary directive to document a class, but I am running into the issue that autosummary only strictly shows the first line of the docstring in the autosummary table. For example,

```
.. currentmodule:: logging
.. autosummary::
  ~Logger.manager
  ~Logger.root
```

produces a table which has:

```
manager   There is [under normal circumstances] just one Manager instance, which
root      A root logger is not that different to any other logger, except that
```

I can understand why this is the default, but is there a way to make it so that the first sentence or the first paragraph are shown?

Answer (score 2):

Your docstrings apparently come from the standard library [logging](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/477508efe4ab/Lib/logging/__init__.py) module. They look like this:

```
class Manager(object):
    """
    There is [under normal circumstances] just one Manager instance, which
    holds the hierarchy of loggers.
    """
```

and

```
class RootLogger(Logger):
    """
    A root logger is not that different to any other logger, except that
    it must have a logging level and there is only one instance of it in
    the hierarchy.
    """
```

This is the code that returns the autosummary string ([`autosummary/__init__.py`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/6e960412308f/sphinx/ext/autosummary/__init__.py)):

```
m = re.search(r"^([A-Z][^A-Z]*?\.\s)", " ".join(doc).strip())
if m:
    summary = m.group(1).strip()
elif doc:
    summary = doc[0].strip()
else:
    summary = '':
```

`doc` is the docstring as *a list of lines*.

The autosummary string is supposed to be [the first sentence of the docstring](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autosummary.html#directive-autosummary). However, there are problems with the regular expression:

1. After the initial uppercase letter, the sentence cannot contain additional uppercase letters.
2. A whitespace character is expected after the period.

This means that the regular expression won't match any of the docstrings above. If the pattern is changed to

```
^([A-Z].*?\.\s?)
```

then it will match both docstrings, and complete first sentences will appear in the output. (This may not be the optimal regex, but at least it works in this case.)